# How to show an alert after reloading the page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make alert box after page reloaded, but it doesn't work.
Please correct my code and tell me why?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    window.location.reload();
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

Comment: Consider that when you're page is reloaded, it's not going to automatically remember the state of the previous page.  When your page reloads all it's going to do is bind a click event and do nothing until someone clicks your button.

Comment: When you reload, you are refreshing the whole page, its not going to have a callback

Comment: i updated my answer in more correct way

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect.
==
see the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127730/jquery-if-condition-is-false-but-still-executed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage):

```
$( "button" ).click( function () {
        sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = true;
        window.location.reload();
    } 
);

$( function () {
        if ( sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad ) {
            alert( "Hello world" );
            sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad = false;
        }
    } 
);
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed some formatting for you. In the future it would be great if you could prefer full words over 'sms speak' - for example "you" over "u". It's easier for readers - thanks and thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Hey I just noticed that this code doesn't work. `if ( sessionStorage.reloadAfterPageLoad )` will always be execute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127730/jquery-if-condition-is-false-but-still-executed/39127785 for details.

Answer (score 2):

That's called onload. It came waaaaay before DOM ready was around, and DOM ready was actually created for the exact reason that onload waited on images.

```
window.onload = function () { 
    alert("It's loaded!");
    //dom not only ready, but everything is loaded
}
```

And a jQuery Javascript solution is to bind the window.onload event in document.ready().

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner Will it not work on the initial go? Won't it show the message the _first_ time the user enters the page?

Comment: only the first or everytime when the user reloads the page?

Comment: If you put the alert in onload function, then It will show the alert message every time the page loads, even the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Hui, a old post. But i´m looking too for a solution to add a script after reload when click a order save button in woocommerce admin order. I think it is a great way to use the sessionStorage and not some hooks. Thanks to Akhil for open the eyes. Maybe some one looking too:

```
jQuery('.button.save_order.button-primary').click(function() {

            sessionStorage.setItem('save_order',true);

});

jQuery( function () {
        if ( sessionStorage.getItem('save_order') ) {
                alert( "Hello world" );
                sessionStorage.removeItem('save_order');
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty method of doing it with `?reload` string in link href like `request.GET` in php

```
<a class="button" href="?reload/">reload and alert</a>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    args = location.search.substr(1);
    if (args=='reload/')alert('page reloaded');  
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that checks for document reloaded and not just document loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Write your own function for alert popup with ok button (i have created parameterized function which accept message, alert type, method name.

> function AlertMessageOk(str, alertType, method)
>   {
>
> ```
>      $('#AlertMessage .divDialogElements').empty();
>
>      $('#AlertMessage .divDialogElements').append(msg);
>
>      if (alertType == "success") {
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTitle').html("Success");
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTypeClass').attr("class", "modal-header alert-success");
>      }
>      else if (alertType == "error") {
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTitle').html("Error");
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTypeClass').attr("class", "modal-header alert-danger");
>      }
>      else if (alertType == "info") {
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTitle').html("Status");
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTypeClass').attr("class", "modal-header alert-info");
>      }
>      else if (alertType == "warning") {
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTitle').html("Warning");
>          $('#AlertMessage #modalAlertHeaderTypeClass').attr("class", "modal-header alert-warning");
>      }
>
>      $('#AlertMessage #btnAlertOk').attr("onclick", method);
>
>      $('#AlertMessage').modal('show');
>  }
> ```

Step 2: On your ajax response.result == true call to AlertMessageOk function. I have passed method name to reload page.

> function buttonActivate_onClick(storeID) {

```
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/configuration/activateStore",
         timeout: 180000,
         data: { StoreID: storeID },
         success: function (response) {
             if (response.result == true) {
                 AlertMessageOk("Store configuration for Store ID " + storeID + " is successfully activated.", "success", "reloadPage();");
             }
         },
         error: function (xhr, textstatus) {
             AlertMessage("Error:   " + xhr.statusText + "  [" + xhr.status + "]", "error");

         }
     });
     $('#wait_load').css("display", "none");
 }


 function reloadPage() {
   location.reload();        
 }
```