# jQuery: if condition is false, but still executed?

Tags: jquery, session-storage

The following code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    sessionStorage.test = false;  

    alert( sessionStorage.test );

    if ( sessionStorage.test ) {
      alert("I dont care about your conditions!");
    }

  });
```

produces the following popups:

> false
>
> I dont care about your conditions!

even though `sessionStorage.test` is clearly set to false. Why is that the case? According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986241/2311074, this should work. What am I doing wrong? I am using XAMPP - does it maybe have problems with sessionStorage? Here is the complete code of my test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
      $(document).ready(function(){
        sessionStorage.test = false;    
        if ( sessionStorage.test ) {
          alert("I dont care about your conditions!");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns"? Javascript code with an `alert()` function call does not "return" anything.

Comment: Mmm, I'd look on the console and have a look there might be an error,  also sessionStorage is a local storage thing for the browser. I'm not sure you can just set an extra variable like that

Comment: @arkascha your right, bad phrasing. I change it. I mean I get 2 popups.

Comment: The Storage API only stores strings and a non-empty string is truthy

Comment: @Andreas so the accepted answer from my linked question is wrong, has 10 votes and no-one checked?

Comment: Yes. The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage-2) clearly says that `.setItem()` expects a `DOMString` as the value parameter and `.getItem()` returns a `DOMString`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default getter/setter for sessionsStorage are:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('keyName', 'value');    
sessionStorage.getItem('keyName')
```

So, for example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('test',false);    
if (sessionStorage.getItem('test') != "false") {
   ..........
}
```

---

Duplicate Topics: 

 - [sessionStorage setItem returns true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481856/sessionstorage-setitem-returns-true-or-false)

 - [sessionStorage isn't working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319686/sessionstorage-isnt-working-as-expected)

Comment: Okay.. So I have to do something like `if( sessionStorage.getItem('test') == "false")`? Thank you! I accept answer as soon as timer is expired.

Comment: i have updated answer, yes, you should `... != "false"`