# JavaScript alert box on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I plan to show alert box if 2 text input doesn't matched. So far I make the alert box onkeyup, but is there another way on to show alert box after page refresh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show an alert after reloading the page in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986198/how-to-show-an-alert-after-reloading-the-page-in-javascript)

Comment: does it depend on data filled before the page refresh?

Comment: Hi @Mark Baijens, yes it depends on page before refresh. On second page first input text using echo value from API response adn the second field statisic value for matched checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localStorage` with `beforeunload` and `unload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("text2").value;
    localStorage.setItem("match", JSON.stringify(text1 == text2));
};
window.onload = function() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("match"))) {
        alert("Texts match!");
    } else {
        alert("Texts don't match!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sample, how to alert if value not matched trying something like JSON.stringify(text1 != text2) but the alert not showing up

Comment: Yes sorry @Bireon I'll add that.

Comment: Hi @Jack Bashford, i tried it but the alert showing on the first load. what i plan to do is, the alert only show after refresh

`<form  method="post" name="member_signup" id="member_signup">
   <input name="email" type="text" required="1" id="email" value="<?php print_r($mail_type_onfirstload);?>"/>
   <input name="emailConfirm" type="text" id="confemail" onChange="confirmEmail()" value="mail@mail.com"/>
   
</form>
`

Comment: @Bireon Try to unset the local storage variable after the alert. The reason it shows on the first pageload is probably because you already set the local storage variable before.

Comment: Hi @MarkBaijens, tried to put the `localStorage.clear();` and also with `window.localStorage.clear();`  but not working, can you please advice how to do in correct way?

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem("match");` should do the job. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need javascript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The simplest way is to just put this at the bottom of your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){ alert("Hi there"));}
</script>
```

This will show the alert when the browser considers the page fully loaded. hope this helps...

Comment: What has jQuery to do with this? Also the OP needs data transported from one page to the other.